# How to build Android application in QT5 using OpenCV on Windows

Tags: android, windows, qt, opencv

I am trying to build application for Android with QT5 on Window OS, using the OpenCV version 2.4.6. on build , I am facing Linker error related to undefined reference for "lopencv_highgui.a".
please Let me know how do I configure Project in QT to use OpenCV  for Android.